Concatenate while dropping specific value strings
I have a dataframe in R called df:
A = c("ok","WA","WA","ok","WA")
B = c("WB","ok","ok","ok","WB")
C = c("WC","ok","WC","ok","WC")
df = tibble(A,B,C)
df
  A     B     C    
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 ok    WB    WC   
2 WA    ok    ok   
3 WA    ok    WC   
4 ok    ok    ok   
5 WA    WB    WC  

I want to create (mutate) a new column that will concatenate all the values that are not OK like this:
  A     B     C     D 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 ok    WB    WC     WB,WC
2 WA    ok    ok     WA
3 WA    ok    WC     WA,WC
4 ok    ok    ok     NO W
5 WA    WB    WC     WA,WB,WC


You could use a paste approach with the help of gsub:
A <- c("ok","WA","WA","ok","WA")
B <- c("WB","ok","ok","ok","WB")
C <- c("WC","ok","WC","ok","WC")
df <- data.frame(A=A, B=B, C=C, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df$D <- paste(df$A, df$B, df$C, sep=",")
df$D <- gsub("^,|,$", "", gsub(",{2,}", ",", gsub("\\bok\\b", ",", df$D)))
df

   A  B  C        D
1 ok WB WC    WB,WC
2 WA ok ok       WA
3 WA ok WC    WA,WC
4 ok ok ok         
5 WA WB WC WA,WB,WC

The basic strategy here is to strip out ok entries, then cleanup the possible dangling commas left from the paste call.

i worked.But if i had 100 columns  instead of 3?

@HomerJaySimpson Nothing else need change except that the call to paste() would contain 100 columns.

@HomerJaySimpson use df$D <- do.call(paste, c(df, sep = ",")) to avoid typing out 100 columns. Or use tidyr::unite: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/unite.html

Using apply and paste
df['D'] <- apply(df, 1, \(x) paste(x[which(x!="ok")], collapse=","))
df
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  A     B     C     D         
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>     
1 ok    WB    WC    "WB,WC"   
2 WA    ok    ok    "WA"      
3 WA    ok    WC    "WA,WC"   
4 ok    ok    ok    ""        
5 WA    WB    WC    "WA,WB,WC"


A non-vectorised alternative using applyrow-wisely and toString with nchar. This might be fast enough on moderate sized data.
df0 = data.frame(A = c("ok","WA","WA","ok","WA"), 
                 B = c("WB","ok","ok","ok","WB"), 
                 C = c("WC","ok","WC","ok","WC"))

df0$D = apply(df0, 1, \(i) {x = sub("ok", "", i); toString(x[nchar(x)>1L]) })
df0$D[df0$D==""] = "NO W"
df0

# A  B  C          D
# 1 ok WB WC     WB, WC
# 2 WA ok ok         WA
# 3 WA ok WC     WA, WC
# 4 ok ok ok       NO W
# 5 WA WB WC WA, WB, WC


Using dplyr/tidyr, replace "ok" with NA, then unite excluding NA, then column bind to original data.frame:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(A:C, ~if_else(.x == "ok", NA, .x))) %>% 
  unite(D, A:C, sep = ",", na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  bind_cols(df, .)

#    A  B  C        D
# 1 ok WB WC    WB,WC
# 2 WA ok ok       WA
# 3 WA ok WC    WA,WC
# 4 ok ok ok         
# 5 WA WB WC WA,WB,WC

